# How to properly filter Spring REST data

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, rest, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Data REST service with a single @Entity and Repository. When I run

$   `curl localhost:8080/api`

I get all the data stored in my repository and it works as expected. I also have a small React front end and I display that data there.

My question is: Where should I filter the data? For example maybe I want all the entries with id > 10. Should I just filter the response in my front end or should I make the REST call in such a way that it returns just the required entries?

If I should do the latter, then how?

Thanks.

Comment: Filter in the backend or  - more specifically - with the database query. The database is optimized for those operations. Thus, you can reduce the data transmitted from the backend to the frontend and reduce the load on the frontend since only data that is requested by the user will be processed by the frontend. Another benefit is that if you have multiple frontends (e.g. website & mobile app), you have to implement filter functionality only once (in the backend) instead of twiche (in each client).

Comment: always in backend if you care about performance, imagine library sending all books data to front-end and then show one to user.. pointless and painful. Just use limit on data repository level to limit query to database

Comment: @Turing85 please extract your comment as an answer otherwise the current upvoted answer is kind of misleading. The main reason should be long time scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is always the case, why would you put extra burden on `front-end` shoulders to filter the results all the time?

Implement a new method which returns the desired results(e.g id > 10) and annotate it with `@Query` and provide `JPQL` or `native query` inside it

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id > 10")
Collection<Customer> findAllActiveCustomers();
```

However, if you choose native query do not forget to put `nativeQuery = true` inside `@Query`

Answer (score 3):

Filter in the backend or - more specifically - with the database query.

The database is optimized for those operations. Thus, you can reduce the data transmitted from the backend to the frontend and reduce the load on the frontend since only data that is requested by the user will be processed by the frontend.

Another benefit is that if you have multiple frontends (e.g. website & mobile app), you have to implement filter functionality only once (in the backend) instead of twice (in each client)